# How to figure out node where I read data from in the replica set via mongodb java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a mongodb replica set with two nodes: EU & US and i set up readPreference=nearest

I know this:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference-mechanics/#replica-set-read-preference-behavior-nearest

But I want to know directly in java code (via mongodb java driver API) who is "nearest"? Or in another way when I execute find() I'd like to know In what node was executed query?
Is it possible to make it via java mongodb driver API?

Comment: I think this can be done via explains, but I'm not sure. Can you post the output of an explain from your java code?

Comment: Thanks. Seems it works